# Can I use AVURLAsset to export video to MP4 with audio?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, video

I am using code to open a video asset using AVURLAsset(), then I watermark the video, and save it using AVAssetExportSession().

Before I open the video, it has sound, and the sound gets lost when I export it using AVAssetExportSession()

Here is how I'm running my code

```
let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: passedVideoURL)

let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
let compositionVideoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
let clipVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

do {
    try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration), ofTrack: clipVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

let parentLayer = CALayer()
let videoLayer = CALayer()
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.height, videoSize.width)
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.height, videoSize.width)
parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
parentLayer.addSublayer(aLayer)


let videoComp = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComp.renderSize = CGSize(width: videoSize.height, height: videoSize.width)
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,30)
videoComp.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, inLayer: parentLayer)

if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) {
exporter.outputURL = completeMovieUrl
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
exporter.videoComposition = videoComp
exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in
            switch exporter.status {
            case  .Failed:
                print("failed \(exporter.error)")
                //completion(url: nil)
                break
            case .Cancelled:
                print("cancelled \(exporter.error)")
                //completion(url: nil)
                break
            default:
                print("complete")

                let u = exporter.outputURL?.path
                self.dataToPass = NSData(contentsOfFile: u!)!

                //try NSFileManager.removeItemAtPath(u)

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("sendToFriend", sender: self)

            }
        })
    }
```

To me it seems like I need to export the audio, and then merge it back to the video? I'm confused as to how to do that process. Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!